# Hide login <form> using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having problems with getting a login box I made to hide. Here is the HTML code I use to make the login box:

```
<center>
  <form name=login>
    <table width=225 border=1 cellpadding=3>
      <tr><td colspan=2><center><font size="+2"><b>Login</b></font></center></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type=text name=username></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type=password name=password></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan=2 align=center>
        <button type="button" onclick="loginNow()">Login</button>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</center>
```

When the "Login" button is clicked, it runs some Javascript code. The `loginNow()` function runs, which verifies the password. Once the password is verified, I need this form to hide.

Can anyone give me some code that will work in this situation?

Comment: That code is not html5, just to let you know. The `<center>` and `<font>` tags are old and should not be used. You should use CSS to style your page. Also, it looks like you are using `<table>` based design, which is not good.

Comment: When you say javascript do you mean javascript or jQuery? If jQuery then you would/could just do `$("form").submit(function(){this.hide();});`

Comment: OK, I'll try to make those changes and see what happens. Any suggestions for the code though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your form in a div with an id:

```
<div id="loginform">
    <form>...</form>
</div>
```

Then, in the `loginNow()` function, use `document.getElementById('loginform').style.visibility = 'hidden'`

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to the center tag like : `center id="login_box"`

And write this script inside the success block of the `loginNow()` code

```
$('#login_box').hide('fast');
```

Or if you cannot add `id` to the `center` tag then add this script inside the success block of the `loginNow()`code

```
$('center').hide('fast');
```

But it will hide all the `center` tags present in the code.